# Efficient way to search within multiple values in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple records like this,

> name: John Doe 
>  aliases: John, Doe, JD 
>  unique_id: 1 
>  ...

My question is how do I search efficiently within the aliases & full name. 
If the search query is any of those 4 (John Doe, John, Doe, JD) I would like to find the unique id (in this case 1).

**What I have done**: I have a very straightforward implementation that loops through the entire data until it finds. It takes a long time since the number of fields is very high.

**Note**: I am using javascript if it helps. Also I have the permission to change the data format (permanently), if it will make the search more efficient. Most of the search queries tend to be one of the aliases rather than full name.

Sample Code: https://jsfiddle.net/nh7yqafh/

```
function SearchJSON(json, query) {
  var champs = json.champs;
  for (var i = 0; i < champs.length; ++i) {
    if (query == champs[i].name)
      return champs[i].unique_id;
    for (var j = 0; j < champs[i].aliases.length; ++j) {
      if (query == champs[i].aliases[j])
        return champs[i].unique_id;
    }
  }
}

//Data format is similar to what vivick said
var json_string = '{"count":5,"champs":[{"name":"Abomination","aliases":["abomination","AB","ABO"],"unique_id":1},{"name":"Black Bolt","aliases":["blackbolt","BB","BBT"],"unique_id":2},{"name":"Black Panther","aliases":["blackpanther","BP","BPR"],"unique_id":3},{"name":"Captain America","aliases":["captainamerica","CA","CAP"],"unique_id":4}]}'
var json = JSON.parse(json_string);

query="CA";
alert( "id of "+query+" is "+SearchJSON(json, query));
```

Comment: `const inputRegex = new RegExp(inputValue, ['g', 'i']); data.filter(obj => inputRegex.test(JSON.stringify(obj)))`

Comment: i would say that `for` loop is much faster than `filter`

Comment: please add the code, you have and some data to test.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric filter is based on a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have a structure similar to the following one :

```
[
  {
    "name": "xxx",
    "aliases": ["x", "xx", "xxx"],
    "unique_id": 1,
    /* [...] */
  },
  /* [...] */ 
]
```

You can then do something like this :

```
const queryParam = /*search query*/;
const arr = /* get the JSON record */;

const IDs = arr
    .filter( entry =>(entry.aliases.includes(queryParam) || queryParam===entry.name) )
    .map(entry=>entry.uniqueId);
```

This will give you an array of IDs which are potential matches.
If you need either 0 or 1 result only :

```
const ID = IDs[0] || null;
```

This will simply retrieve the first matched ID if there's one, otherwise it will set ID to null.

NB:
If you use an object of objects instead of an array of object, there's just a little bit of modifications to do (mainly using `Object.entries`) but it still is trivial.

PS:
I would recommend to always add the full name in the aliases, this will ease the filtering part (no `||` would be required).